# Copying azure blob that is being updated

Tags: azure

I'm copying a blob and its associated snapshots from one Azure storage account to another, using Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy:

```
$status = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcContainer $container -SrcBlob $blob 
  -SrcContext $srccontext -DestContainer $container 
  -DestBlob $blob -DestContext $destContext -Force
```

However, when another application updates the blob, the copy operation fails.

```
$copyState = $status | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState 
$copyState.Status -eq "Failed"
```

Is there a way to copy a blob or one of its snapshots while the blob is being updated?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Are you getting `412 Precondition Failed` error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx), the topic of async blob copy is discussed in detail. In particular, it discusses how the copy operation locks onto the blob's ETag, and if the ETag changes (e.g. you changed the blob), the copy fails.

To avoid this, the article suggests getting a lease on the blob.

The other thing you can do is copy a snapshot to a new blob, as a snapshot won't be modified.

Comment: I had seen that article too. Problem is that the source blob contains a database for a live system, so getting a lease is not attractive. Also, a snapshot only contains differences with the underlying blob, so it too changes when the underlying blob changes (when the blob changes, the differences become bigger).

Comment: The client has now decided to live with the restriction that they can't copy the blob while the system is live (they'll take a copy while the system is offline right after deploying a new version).

Comment: I think you misunderstand snapshots. A snapshot, once taken, doesn't change. Forget about the underlying pages - logically, your app won't see a snapshot change. So... you take a snapshot, and then you make a copy of a snapshot to another blob. This lets you make copies without taking your app offline. And no lease required.